# How to do ruby deep copy in chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, deep-copy

I want to deep copy a chef attribute.

I try to use Marshal:

```
default[:deep_clone_test] = {};
Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(default[:deep_clone_test]))
```

But I get the error: "TypeError: can't dump hash with default proc"

How can I deep copy a chef attribute?

Comment: What kind of object do you have there that it's not marshalable? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: That hash doesn't have default proc, and it's perfectly marshalable. I didn't run in chef context, yes, but I doubt that chef violates basic ruby principles. :shrug: This is to say, I don't know the answer to your question. :)

Comment: Maybe not in Chef? I put these lines in a `attribute/default.rb` file.

Comment: Can you try to provide a [mcve]? `Marshal.load(Marshal.dump({}))` clearly works fine, so I don't know how to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Yes `Marshal.load(Marshal.dump({}))` but not `default[:deep_clone_test] = {};Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(default[:deep_clone_test]));` This is the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. It needs to be run in Chef.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to inherit from defaults attributes (several times).

Comment: In what kind of context? Like you want to invent your own layering system in addition to Chef's existing one?

Comment: @coderanger I have some configurations to a node which are slightly different. I want to clone the first one and modify it a bit to avoid rewrite it multiple times.

Comment: Write a helper function instead. It's code, you can do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended doing this:

`JSON.parse(my_json.to_json, symbolize_names: true)`